# FileChannel.lock running for a long time

Tags: chronicle

So I have a simple code where I listens to jms msg and writes it to different chronicle queue, depending on the fix tag.

```
public void onEvent(InputEvent inputEvent) {
    String msg = ((SimpleInputEvent) inputEvent).getMessage();
    int start = msg.indexOf("\u000155=");
    if (start == -1){
        // dropping it
        return;
    }
    char symbol = msg.charAt(start+4);
    for (int i = m_ranges.length - 1; i >= 0; i --){
        if (symbol >= m_ranges[i]){
            m_appenders[i].writeText(msg);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I'm running some performance test and I see that it has this kind of profile

[image: Profile]

The main thread is running the above function. 
And we can see the FileChannel.lock is running for 30 seconds straight! I'm not sure what it's doing. I created the queue like this

```
        m_queues[j] = SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.binary(path + "_" + m_ranges[j]).build();
        m_appenders[j] = m_queues[j].acquireAppender();
```

Thanks!

After reading more, I increased the blockSize to 512Mb which I will never reach in this test. However, I still reach a bottleneck in my performance test. In particular, sar shows

I increased the bufferSize to larger than I would have written to cq4 file this code should never kick in. But I still see some bottleneck in my system. If I turn on sar, I see

05:05:41 AM       tps      rtps      wtps   bread/s   bwrtn/s
....
05:10:12 AM    714.14      0.00    714.14      0.00   6901.01

05:05:41 AM       DEV       tps  rd_sec/s  wr_sec/s  avgrq-sz  avgqu-sz     await     svctm     %util
...
05:10:12 AM rootvg-lvar    422.00      0.00   3376.00      8.00      0.10      0.23      0.00      0.20

what should I do to avoid a big chunk of write to desk?

Comment: can you tell me your OS/kernel version and Java version?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running a recent Linux, what you are seeing in SAR is the kernel writing pages from the page cache to your disk.

Chronicle Queue uses memory-mapped files rather that making any 'direct' writes to disk. So the operating system is in control of when data from a queue file is actually persisted to storage.

If you wish to reduce the size of those writes, you can try to configure the kernel to flush pages at a shorter interval.